# Covering as few points as possible with a spherical cap

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

This is a generalisation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313592/how-many-points-must-the-arc-intersect/2313679#2313679), posted yesterday.

If we have a set of points $x_i$ on the surface of a sphere, or more generally a $d$-dimensional hypersphere, and we have a hyperspherical cap with a surface area a proportion $p$ of that of the whole sphere, is there always a position for the spherical cap such that it intersects no more than $p$ of the $x_i$?

The argument I used for the previous question doesn't seem to easily generalise because spherical caps can't cleanly tile a sphere.

Comment: An averaging argument should still work. Let the group $G=SO(n)$ act on the sphere $S^n$ in the usual way. Consider the space $SO(n)\times S^n$ with the first component equipped with the Haar measure of $SO(n)$ and the latter component with the usual measure of the sphere. Integrate the sum of suitable bump functions concentrated at $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of the $x_i$s over the set $M=\{(g,\overline{x})\mid g\cdot\overline{x}\in C\}$. Apply Fubini to do it in two different ways et cetera. A bit fuzzy, and I don't see all the details, but probably works.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I can see what you're doing here but I'm a little unfamiliar with this kind of proof- is there a particular reference you could suggest I might be able to read about this?

Comment: Just to be sure, we're dealing with a finite number of points $x_i$?

Comment: @N.Bach yes, although I would also be interested in the continuous limit where we have a density function. From what I can see, the method above would apply to each.